# How to show a dialog to confirm that the user wishes to exit an Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, activity-finish

I've been trying to show a "Do you want to exit?" type of dialog when the user attempts to exit an Activity.

However I can't find the appropriate API hooks.  `Activity.onUserLeaveHint()` initially looked promising, but I can't find a way to stop the Activity from finishing.

Comment: Is it absolutely essential that you have this prompt? When a user wants to finish an Activity, they should be able to do so immediately. You may want to rethink your strategy.

Comment: Displaying an exit confirmation option is compulsory for listing at Samsung's App store. One of my Apps was rejected for not having this.

Comment: That's obnoxious, @Samsung.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do upon exiting. If the state is preserved and you can just navigate back, showing a dialog might not be necessary. However, in one of my applications I clean up cookies, data, and close connections for good with a final commit of data. User's should be made aware of the finality of their choice, especially since it is uncommon today to have that sense of finality in a mobile application.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes people (me too) confuse the options and back button since I sometimes use 180deg rotation. So I find it quite necessary that if we are exiting it should not be done by mistake.

Comment: I've created a solution for this. Please read more http://chintanrathod.com/display-alert-on-back-button-pressed-in-android-studio/

Comment: @ Tom R: Totally disagree. There are apps that you dont want to finish by accident. They work in business environment and so on.

Answer (score 402):

In Android 2.0+ this would look like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Closing Activity")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();    
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
```

In earlier versions it would look like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Ask the user if they want to quit
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Stop the activity
                YourClass.this.finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
        .show();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also in 2.0 and above there is a new onBackPressed event that is recommended over onKeyDown

http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

There is a section here talking about the changes and new recommended  approach.

http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/sdk/android-2.0.html

Comment: Blog post on catching the back key here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Note that this does not allow you to catch other ways the user can leave your app: pressing home, selecting a notification, receiving a phone call, etc.

Comment: This works perfectly but how do you force code execution to stop while it's being showed to the user?

Comment: found it, this is a great solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381296/android-wait-on-user-input-from-dialog

Comment: This is the method() what I am looking for but I did not know where to call this method().

Comment: Consider android.R.string.no and android.R.string.yes for the standard "Cancel" and "Accept" labels.

Comment: @user2841300 You just need to copy and paste the onBackPressed method into whichever of your activities you need to override the 'back' behaviour for.

Comment: make sure to remove super.onBackPressed(); or else it will force close the app..

Answer (score 191):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ExampleActivity.super.onBackPressed();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();
}
```

Comment: A comment was made by elBradford: Calling the super onBackPressed is better than assuming onBackPressed will only call finish(). Even if that's true now, it may not be true in future APIs `CustomTabActivity.super.onBackPressed`

Comment: @mplungjan Can you clarify your comment... Are you saying it's better to replace the `finish()` code with `super.onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: Comment is 3 years old. I have no idea what is good practice in 2015

Comment: @mplungjan Your comment referred to future APIs, but it would be helpful if you could clarify anyway.

Comment: No probs. Well, I've just tried `MyActivity.super.onBackPressed();` and it works fine for me. It seems to most logical approach, too - to call the method you are overriding if you want the standard behaviour when user taps "No."

Answer (score 33):

Have modified @user919216 code .. and made it compatible with WebView

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();

    }
    else
    {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 26):

I'd prefer to exit with double tap on the back button than with an exit Dialog.

In this solution, it show a toast when go back for the first time, warning that another back press will close the App. In this example less than 4 seconds.

```
private Toast toast;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", 4000);
    toast.show();
    this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  } else {
    if (toast != null) {
    toast.cancel();
  }
  super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

Token from: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/back-button-behavior.html

Comment: This one is definitely my favorite as the Dialogbox can be cumbersome. I changed it slightly to make it 3 seconds and it seems a bit more natural with that marker. Thanks for the post.

Comment: on double back press ideally app should me exit but in my code it's open a login Activity(means back activity with enabled spinner )

Answer (score 22):

If you are not sure if the call to "back" will exit the app, or will take the user to another activity, you can wrap the above answers in a check, isTaskRoot(). This can happen if your main activity can be added to the back stack multiple times, or if you are manipulating your back stack history.

```
if(isTaskRoot()) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                YourActivity.super.onBackPressed;
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Totally searching for this. Thank you.. I think this must be marked as answer. Others are useless. I was searching for the feature which isTaskRoot() method does.

Answer (score 7):

in China, most App will confirm the exit by "click twice":

```java
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Lambda:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(getString(R.string.exit_msg))
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.info))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), (arg0, arg1) -> {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            finish();
        })
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), (arg0, arg1) -> {
        })
        .show();
```

You also need to set level language to support java 8 in your gradle.build:

```
compileOptions {
       targetCompatibility 1.8
       sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First remove `super.onBackPressed();` from `onbackPressed()` method than and below code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Just put this code in your first activity 

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
        else {
// if your using fragment then you can do this way
            int fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (fragments == 1) {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();


            } else {
                if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else {

           super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: y first activity, cant i put it in activity in middle. because now it jsut closes the current activity and it shows the previous one

Answer (score 2):

I like a @GLee approach and using it with fragment like below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isTaskRoot()) {
        new ExitDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Dialog using Fragment:

```
public class ExitDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.exit_question)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getDialog().cancel();
                }
            })
            .create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to *show a `Toast`/`Snackbar` on the first back press asking to press back again to Exit*, which is a lot less intrusive than showing an `AlertDialog` to confirm if user wants to exit the app.

You can use the [`DoubleBackPress Android Library`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress) to achieve this with a few lines of code. [Example GIF showing similar behaviour.](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress#ToastDisplayExample)

To begin with, add the dependency to your application :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:double-back-press:0.0.1'
}
```

---

Next, in your Activity, implement the required behaviour.

```
// set the Toast to be shown on FirstBackPress (ToastDisplay - builtin template)
// can be replaced by custom action (new FirstBackPressAction{...})
FirstBackPressAction firstBackPressAction = new ToastDisplay().standard(this);

// set the Action on DoubleBackPress
DoubleBackPressAction doubleBackPressAction = new DoubleBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        // TODO : Exit the application
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
};

// setup DoubleBackPress behaviour : close the current Activity
DoubleBackPress doubleBackPress = new DoubleBackPress()
        .withDoublePressDuration(3000)     // msec - wait for second back press
        .withFirstBackPressAction(firstBackPressAction)
        .withDoubleBackPressAction(doubleBackPressAction);
```

Finally, set this as the behaviour on back press.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackPress.onBackPressed();
}
```