# Allow dialog to be displayed before or during onPause()?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have created a simple game for Android; I want to prevent users from sending the game to the background by pressing the home or back buttons accidentally. I planned on using a dialog to confirm the user's action. What I want is similar to what Sirius does with their app, if you need an illustration.

I tried adding this action to an overridden onPause(), but the activity vanishes right after the dialog is displayed, so I don't think I'm going about this the right way. How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only override the back button.  You cannot override the home button.  This is more or less for security reasons (to prevent someone's phone from getting hi-jacked).

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459848/android-prompt-user-to-save-changes-when-back-button-is-pressed) two [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257963/android-how-to-show-dialog-to-confirm-user-wishes-to-exit-activity).

Comment: The second link you gave provided the answer.