# How to pause code for results from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I run an AlertDialog asking the user to get a photo from the camera or the gallery the program doesn't seem to wait for the results and continues to execute.  This causes the result to not get saved properly into the Image View field.  Ignore the unused variables as I am not done coding this activity yet.  I am new to this so any other criticism is appreciated.

```
package ca.android.whitehead.mycardswallet;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AddEditCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etCardName;
private ImageView ivCardFront, ivCardBack, ivBarcode;
private Button btnCardFront, btnCardBack, btnBarcode;

private Bitmap image;

private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int CAPTUR_PHOTO = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit_card);

    etCardName = findViewById(R.id.etCardName);
    ivCardFront = findViewById(R.id.ivCardFront);
    ivCardBack = findViewById(R.id.ivCardBack);
    ivBarcode = findViewById(R.id.ivBarcode);
    btnCardFront = findViewById(R.id.btnCardFront);
    btnCardBack = findViewById(R.id.btnCardBack);
    btnBarcode = findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);

    btnCardFront.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCardBack.setOnClickListener(this);
}

   @Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCardFront:
            getImage();
            if (image != null)
            {
                ivCardFront.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnCardBack:
            getImage();
            if (image != null)
            {
                ivCardBack.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
            break;

    }
}

public void getImage()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCardActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick from gallery or take new picture");
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    builder.setItems(R.array.uploadImage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTUR_PHOTO);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            // this is the image selected by the user
            Uri imageUri = resultData.getData();

            if (imageUri != null) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CAPTUR_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            // this is the image selected by the user
            image = (Bitmap)Objects.requireNonNull(resultData.getExtras()).get("data");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: wait on user input from dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381296/android-wait-on-user-input-from-dialog)

Comment: So basically you should put the `if (image != null){...}` as next statement after `image = ... `.

Comment: Both `show()` on an `AlertDialog` and `startActivityForResult()` are asynchronous. Make use of the image if and when you get one, in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking CommonsWare advice.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AddEditCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etCardName;
private ImageView ivCardFront, ivCardBack, ivBarcode;
private Button btnCardFront, btnCardBack, btnBarcode;

private Bitmap image;

private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
private static final int CAPTURE_PHOTO = 200;
private static final int FRONT_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int BACK_IMAGE = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit_card);

    etCardName = findViewById(R.id.etCardName);
    ivCardFront = findViewById(R.id.ivCardFront);
    ivCardBack = findViewById(R.id.ivCardBack);
    ivBarcode = findViewById(R.id.ivBarcode);
    btnCardFront = findViewById(R.id.btnCardFront);
    btnCardBack = findViewById(R.id.btnCardBack);
    btnBarcode = findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);

    btnCardFront.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCardBack.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCardFront:
            getImage(1);
            break;
        case R.id.btnCardBack:
            getImage(2);
            break;

    }
}

public void getImage(final int image)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCardActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick from gallery or take new picture");
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    builder.setItems(R.array.uploadImage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO + image);

                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_PHOTO + image);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

private void setBitmap(Uri imageUri, ImageView imageView)
{
    if (imageUri != null) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == (SELECT_PHOTO + FRONT_IMAGE)) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                setBitmap(resultData.getData(), ivCardFront);
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == (SELECT_PHOTO + BACK_IMAGE)) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                setBitmap(resultData.getData(), ivCardBack);
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_PHOTO + FRONT_IMAGE) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                // this is the image selected by the user
                ivCardFront.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)Objects.requireNonNull(resultData.getExtras()).get("data"));
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_PHOTO + BACK_IMAGE) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                // this is the image selected by the user
                ivCardBack.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)Objects.requireNonNull(resultData.getExtras()).get("data"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}