# Parsing the data and showing the result using a dialog box/toast

Tags: android, parsing, dialog

I want to parse the below given data using resultsRequestSOAP object in order to display the message "registered successfully" if the log-cat responsecode== 1, "try again"if response is 0 in my activity,  I tried a lot  to show the dialog box according to the logcat response but as I am new to android I couldn't able to do that. please some one help me with code snippet if possible.
I m getting the responses 1,0 in my logcat but with this I want to display the alert dialog box in my activity

Help is always appreciated...!

```
request.addProperty("email", email);
request.addProperty("contact", contact);
request.addProperty("fname", fname);
request.addProperty("lname", lname);
request.addProperty("gender", gender);
request.addProperty("dateofbirth", dob);
request.addProperty("password", password);
request.addProperty("latitude", 76);
request.addProperty("longitude", 82);
request.addProperty("device_id", "12345"); 

aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); 
aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
```

Comment: can you give us the xml response ?? it would be easier but Soapobject cotain other soapbojects like the xml.

Comment: @subspider,    Hi, in logcat I m getting the following response,   RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult=1; } here after checking the response I want to show the message like "Registered successfully"

Comment: RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult=1; then sucessfully registerd RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult=0; database error/already registerd , RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult= -1; field is empty  ,     these r the three possible cases in logcat response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int result = Integer.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP.getProprety("RegisterUserResult"));
```

if not working try

```
resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)resultsRequestSOAP.getProprety(0);
int result = Integer.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP.getProprety("RegisterUserResult").toString());
```

I think that's it

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response, I m getting the response as 1 in logcat. using this I want to show the dialog box in my activity, I mean if response = 1 then SUCCESS otherwise TRYAGAIN. how to do this?(my actual requirement)

Comment: @Raj good well if you go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257963/android-how-to-show-dialog-to-confirm-user-wishes-to-exit-activity 
use these

Comment: @Raj if you couldn't do it tell me ok

Comment: I tried it But I couldn't, I think I should use asynctask to do this.