# create confirm dialog class on android

Tags: android, dialog, confirm

i try to make own confirm dialog class with boolean value as result. i have read any tutorial or suggestion but the results are not as I want.

The problem is I hate to write long coding, I wanted to write a simple coding. This comparison delphi to android in writing confirmation dialog

Delphi:

`if MessageDlg ('Message Text', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0)`

Android:

```
boolean answer = false;

public boolean Confirm (Activity act, String Title, String ConfirmText,
CancelBtn String, String OkBtn) {
  AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder (act). Create ();
  dialog.setTitle (Title);
  dialog.setMessage (ConfirmText);
  dialog.setCancelable (false);
  dialog.setButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, OkBtn,
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
  answer = true;
  }
});
dialog.setButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, CancelBtn,
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
  public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
    answer = false;
  }
});
dialog.setIcon (android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
return answer;
}
```

the question is can I create a class that generate a confirmation dialogue will produce a Boolean value true or false, just as in Delphi.

confirmation dialog so that the class can be used in class or another activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a dialog to confirm that the user wishes to exit an Android Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257963/how-to-show-a-dialog-to-confirm-that-the-user-wishes-to-exit-an-android-activity)

Comment: I have read that post, but that's not the answer I expected. I want to create a separate class that confirm dialog can be accessed by all the activity with a more efficient coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is not always conventional. You can't show a dialog and wait for it to be displayed, then do something.

You need to show a dialog, and respond to the yes / no buttons in a callback.

Something like this is one solution:

```
/**
 * Display a confirm dialog. 
 * @param activity
 * @param title
 * @param message
 * @param positiveLabel
 * @param negativeLabel
 * @param onPositiveClick runnable to call (in UI thread) if positive button pressed. Can be null
 * @param onNegativeClick runnable to call (in UI thread) if negative button pressed. Can be null
 */
public static final void confirm(
        final Activity activity, 
        final int title, 
        final int message,
        final int positiveLabel, 
        final int negativeLabel,
        final Runnable onPositiveClick,
        final Runnable onNegativeClick) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            dialog.setTitle(title);
            dialog.setMessage(message);
            dialog.setCancelable (false);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(positiveLabel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                    if (onPositiveClick != null) onPositiveClick.run();
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(negativeLabel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                    if (onNegativeClick != null) onNegativeClick.run();
                }
            });
            dialog.setIcon (android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            dialog.show();

        }

}
```

To use the above method, something like this can be used:

```
        Alert.confirm(activity, R.string.titFileExport, R.string.lblFileConfirmOverwrite, 
                R.string.yes, R.string.no, 
                new Runnable() { public void run() {performExport(activity, app, currentSong, saveFile);}}, 
                null);
        return;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom layout for dialogs, or for some more sophisticated needs it may be much easier to create Activity themed as dialog and call it with `startActivityForResults()`. Just design you "dialog" UI and theme your activity, by adding this to activity Manifest entry:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: sory i'm beginer on android programming can you give some link or example code

Answer (score 0):

OK. so you want a single method or class that you will just pass values and that will call everytime you need a dialog box. i have made a program that recieve sms and show it in dialog box . you just have to pass values as intent and do whatever you like. its a simple program you can modify as u want. 
http://zohaibbrohi.blogspot.com/2012/11/recieve-sms-and-show-it-in-activity-as.html

Comment: Thank for all that try answer my question but finally i get my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using cordova, the latest stable version is 2.1.0 It has a navigator.notification (alert or confirm in this case) API

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification
The only drawback is that with blackberry, native apps are more error prone