# How to exit from the application while pressing back button from fragment

Tags: android

I am adding fragment in the activity.While user press back button from one fragment screen .I need to exit from the application can anybody tell how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following method to exit from from `fragment`

```
getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true); 
getActivity().finish();
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

Capture the back button press, clear the stack of activities so your activity is at the back of it, and the close it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack (true)
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read More at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257963/how-to-show-a-dialog-to-confirm-that-the-user-wishes-to-exit-an-android-activity/)

```
private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int fragments = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (fragments == 0) {
            // make layout invisible since last fragment will be removed
            if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 3000) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", 3000);
                toast.show();
                this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }else{
                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                }
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

        }else{
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One safe way when you may have multiple fragments added/replaced is to count the backstack and exit via this: (this would be inside main activity)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This way if you press *BACK* on a fragment that is not your main, only that fragment is removed and once you reach the lower-most fragment (first one you added) then it will call the `onBackPressed` of super class which could be your `.. BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity` and then inside this *BaseActivity* add this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pressing back button will be detected from your `Activity`
Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using getActivity.finish() I exit from at the application